# Unity 3D connection to (MS)SQL server

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection, unity-game-engine

I have a school project - connect to MSSQL database, get some data for particular device, then in unity draw a graph, which will be bounded with some 3D object (devices in building etc.), I have time until December. It can be a desktop application or web application, or both. But I don't know, if on some free web server I can use Unity3D and technologies which I am asking for.

I was looking through the Internet and I couldn't find (even in Unity3D documentation), how it exactly works, I mean: on which technology Unity runs, which technologies it uses, or can be use. I find some sharps on forums, but you know...

I hope, there is a possibility how to to use in some way .NET to connect to MSSQL server... But I am looking for other ways, how to connect to database. I found [SmartFoxServer](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) and it looks great but maybe it is unnecessary? Some poeple recommended to write own socket, but I have no skills for do that in such a short time (and if I consider, that I have no clue how Unity works).

I am starting with Unity, so maybe someone know a good book about my questions. I found only game development, but nothing about Unity itself.

Thx a lot guys.

(If something, my Skype: teddinka1)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What have you tried?  What issues are you encountering?

Comment: I want know, on which technologies Unity3D runs - Ill need to write these basic informations to the output paper. After knowing it, I can easily chose or find further technologies to work with and then I can decide, which Ill finally use for work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding SQL server connection this answer might be a good starting point [connect to the sql database](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8171/connect-to-the-sql-database.html).

The bigger problem will be finding a free hoster that provides a MS SQL server but I think there should be everything within your school's intranet. So I would rcomment to focus on the stand alone client. Anyway you can easily generate a web app and put it just in some accessible directory on any server, but a web app creates generally a little bit more hassle in respect of access restrictions, DB connections, ...

Developing in Unity is pretty straightforward and well documented. Start with the [Basics in the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityBasics.html) than proceed to the sections you are interested in and look at the example projects. Further on there are complete projects (some of them for free) in Unity's asset store.

Comment: Yeah, developing in unity is great, no problem with that. So do U think, I just need to use Mono library for connection? There are no way for using .net frameworks? :(

Comment: @Alisator No, I have no experience with combining .NET and Unity

Comment: So mono then... It might be nice too :)

Comment: @Alisator yes Mono is OK so far. Don't forget to mark the answe as answered, provided that it helped you

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick tutorial how to achieve this: https://roderickvella.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/write-data-from-unity-3d-to-sql-server-using-asp-net/